# How conditially interrupt camunda process instance from event subprocess

Tags: java, camunda, bpmn

I want to check some condition in my event subprocess and terminate the parent process depending on that condition. So it will be something like this
[image: example]
I want to start event subprocess by non-interrupting event, and inside it after checking some conditionals (consists of some http requests to other systems, too complicated for place it in listener) a want to decide if interrupt parent process or not. But terminate end event doesnt work as I want, it terminates only subprocess instances. So are there any options to do this?))

Tried to stop instance via searching by process ID, but I think there should be simpler solution without loading a DB more than need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminating end event is scoped by the embedded sub process, so it will not affect the parent. To dynamically interrupt the parent process, create another embedded sub process, which uses an interrupting start event.

How about this?

[image]

An alternative solution could use a BPMNError end event in the embedded sub process.